# jsoup to strip only html tags not new line character?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, end-of-line

I have below content in Java where I want to strip only html tags but not new line characters

```
<p>test1 <b>test2</b> test 3 </p> //line 1
<p>test4 </p> //line 2
```

If I open above content in text rich editor, line 1 and line 2 are displayed in different lines(without showing `</p>` tag).But in notepad content is shown along with `</p>` tags. To remove all html tags I used

```
Jsoup.parse(aboveContent).text()
```

It removes all html characters. But it shows all line 1 and line 2 in same line in notepad. Somehow Jsoup also removes newline character.

**What I tried:-**

I also tried replacing `</p>` with `\r\n` and then do to remove html tags

```
 Jsoup.parse(contentWith\r\n-Insteadof-</p>Tag ).text()
```

but still Jsoup removes end of line character(as in the debugger I can see both line1 and line2) in same line.

How I can make Jsoup  to strip only html character but not new line character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a single line because `text()` remove all whitepace characters.
But you can use a `StringBuilder` and insert each line there:

```
final String html = "<p>test1 <b>test2</b> test 3 </p>"
                    + "<p>test4 </p>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);        
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


for( Element element : doc.select("p") )
{
    /*
     * element.text() returns the text of this element (= without tags).
     */
    sb.append(element.text()).append('\n');
}

System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
```

**Output:**

```
test1 test2 test 3
test4
```

Answer (score 16):

You can also do this:

```
public static String cleanNoMarkup(String input) {
    final Document.OutputSettings outputSettings = new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    String output = Jsoup.clean(input, "", Whitelist.none(), outputSettings);
    return output;

}
```

The important things here are:
1. Whitelist.none() - so no markup is allowed 
2..prettyPrint(false) - so linebreaks are not removed