# Replacing newline characters with <br> inside a child element using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am having a problem replacing line breaks inside all `<pre>` elements in a given HTML using Jsoup.
Here is what I tried so far, and the problem I am facing. 
I am trying to replace all the `\n` characters with `<br>` for the innerHtml in all the `<pre>` tags only. I want to leave the rest of the content as it is.
The code is:

```
String body = "<p>This is the output:</p>\n<pre class=\"lang-xml prettyprint prettyprinted\">\n<code><span class=\"dec\">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">\n</span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;HTML&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">\n    </span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;HEAD&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">\n        </span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;META</span><span class=\"pln\"> </span><span class=\"atn\">http-equiv</span><span class=\"pun\">=</span><span class=\"atv\">\"Content-Type\"</span><span class=\"pln\"> </span><span class=\"atn\">content</span><span class=\"pun\">=</span><span class=\"atv\">\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"</span><span class=\"tag\">&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">\n        </span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;TITLE&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">GeteBayOfficialTime</span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;/TITLE&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">\n    </span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;/HEAD&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">\n    </span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;BODY&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">\n\n* About to connect() to api.ebay.com port 443 (#0)\n*   Trying 66.135.211.100... * Timeout\n*   Trying 66.135.211.140... * Timeout\n*   Trying 66.211.179.150... * Timeout\n*   Trying 66.211.179.180... * Timeout\n*   Trying 66.135.211.101... * Timeout\n*   Trying 66.211.179.148... * Timeout\n* connect() timed out!\n* Closing connection #0\n</span><span class=\"tag\">&lt;P&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\">Error sending request</span></code></pre>";
            log.info("printing before creating a Jsoup Doc "+  body);
            Document bodyDom = Jsoup.parse(body);
            log.info("printing after creating a Jsoup Doc "+  bodyDom.html());

            Elements preTags = bodyDom.getElementsByTag("pre");

            for (Element pre : preTags) {
                pre.html(pre.html().replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />"));
                log.info("Pre element with linebreaks replaced -" + pre);
            }

            body = bodyDom.html();
```

Here is the log, seems like the html source is losing newline characters once I parse the Jsoup document.   :

```
**2013-12-10 10:14:59 INFO  FormattingTest:166** - printing before creating a Jsoup Doc <p>This is the output:</p>
<pre class="lang-xml prettyprint prettyprinted">
<code><span class="dec">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"&gt;</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="tag">&lt;HTML&gt;</span><span class="pln">
    </span><span class="tag">&lt;HEAD&gt;</span><span class="pln">
        </span><span class="tag">&lt;META</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="atn">http-equiv</span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="atv">"Content-Type"</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="atn">content</span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="atv">"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"</span><span class="tag">&gt;</span><span class="pln">
        </span><span class="tag">&lt;TITLE&gt;</span><span class="pln">GeteBayOfficialTime</span><span class="tag">&lt;/TITLE&gt;</span><span class="pln">
    </span><span class="tag">&lt;/HEAD&gt;</span><span class="pln">
    </span><span class="tag">&lt;BODY&gt;</span><span class="pln">

* About to connect() to api.ebay.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 66.135.211.100... * Timeout
*   Trying 66.135.211.140... * Timeout
*   Trying 66.211.179.150... * Timeout
*   Trying 66.211.179.180... * Timeout
*   Trying 66.135.211.101... * Timeout
*   Trying 66.211.179.148... * Timeout
* connect() timed out!
* Closing connection #0
</span><span class="tag">&lt;P&gt;</span><span class="pln">Error sending request</span></code></pre>


**2013-12-10 10:14:59 INFO  FormattingTest:168** - printing after creating a Jsoup Doc <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>This is the output:</p> 
  <pre class="lang-xml prettyprint prettyprinted">
<code><span class="dec">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd&quot;&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;HTML&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;HEAD&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;META</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="atn">http-equiv</span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="atv">&quot;Content-Type&quot;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="atn">content</span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="atv">&quot;text/html; charset=iso-8859-1&quot;</span><span class="tag">&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;TITLE&gt;</span><span class="pln">GeteBayOfficialTime</span><span class="tag">&lt;/TITLE&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;/HEAD&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;BODY&gt;</span><span class="pln"> * About to connect() to api.ebay.com port 443 (#0) * Trying 66.135.211.100... * Timeout * Trying 66.135.211.140... * Timeout * Trying 66.211.179.150... * Timeout * Trying 66.211.179.180... * Timeout * Trying 66.135.211.101... * Timeout * Trying 66.211.179.148... * Timeout * connect() timed out! * Closing connection #0 </span><span class="tag">&lt;P&gt;</span><span class="pln">Error sending request</span></code></pre>
 </body>
</html>
2013-12-10 10:14:59 INFO  FormattingTest:174 - Pre element with linebreaks replaced -  <pre class="lang-xml prettyprint prettyprinted"><code><span class="dec">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd&quot;&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;HTML&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;HEAD&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;META</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="atn">http-equiv</span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="atv">&quot;Content-Type&quot;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="atn">content</span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="atv">&quot;text/html; charset=iso-8859-1&quot;</span><span class="tag">&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;TITLE&gt;</span><span class="pln">GeteBayOfficialTime</span><span class="tag">&lt;/TITLE&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;/HEAD&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="tag">&lt;BODY&gt;</span><span class="pln"> * About to connect() to api.ebay.com port 443 (#0) * Trying 66.135.211.100... * Timeout * Trying 66.135.211.140... * Timeout * Trying 66.211.179.150... * Timeout * Trying 66.211.179.180... * Timeout * Trying 66.135.211.101... * Timeout * Trying 66.211.179.148... * Timeout * connect() timed out! * Closing connection #0 </span><span class="tag">&lt;P&gt;</span><span class="pln">Error sending request</span></code></pre>
```

Not sure what's wrong. This is working with another html source -
"\nResponse :\n some thext \n \ndsjkhskjdh sdjhasjkdas \n"

Gets properly converted to  -

```
Response :
 some text 
 
dsjkhskjdh sdjhasjkdas
```

Not sure why the first sample doesnt !!

Comment: You might have better luck using [parseBodyFragment](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html) because your HTML sample is not a complete page.

Comment: Thanks, will try that and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately that din't help, its still removing all the line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you try to do this:

```
    Jsoup.parse("\nText\nNex").html();
```

you get:

```
    text nex
```

From [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text), you can do this:

```
    Document bodyDom = Jsoup.parse(body.replaceAll("(\\r\\n|\\n)", "<br />"));
```

That's replace the linebreak before parse the document.

#### Only replace `<pre>` tags

For replace only the linebreaks between two `pre` tags, use a regular expression to extract they and replace:

```
    Pattern preP = Pattern.compile("<pre.*?>.+?</pre>", Pattern.DOTALL
            | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = preP.matcher(body);
    while (m.find()) {
        String toReplace = m.group();
        String replaced = toReplace.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />");
        body = body.replace(toReplace, replaced);
    }
```

The `.+*` is a greedy qualifiers, it match the first appearance of `/pre`, You can try with regex, but it's not possible, see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) for a better explanation. I recommend you to use the next option.

You can see examples of the regex [here](http://fiddle.re/uxhv8).

#### `clean` the string before parse

From [the second asnwers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453047/jsoup-to-strip-only-html-tagsnot-new-line-character#2) you can use:

```
    Document.OutputSettings outputSettings = new Document.OutputSettings()
            .prettyPrint(false);
    body = Jsoup.clean(body, "", Whitelist.relaxed(), outputSettings);
```

and after (as in your original code):

```
    pre.html(pre.html().replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />"));
```

The `prettyPrint` option make the `clean` method to escape the linebreaks, and later the parser handle it correctly

Cheers

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. However This does not help because - If you look at the code I am looking to replace the line breaks with <br> only inside the Pre elements. replacing them before parsing with Jsoup will defeat the purpose as I will be loosing all the line breaks well before I get to parse the Pre elements.

Comment: Hi, I added more code to work with your case, in my local test it work's, please tell me if I am wrong. Cheers

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. quick question, Does this take care of pre elements with any attributes or no attributes at all?  I will give this a try now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the regex solution worked well. Only question I now have is , does this match any pre elements with any attributes or with no attributes? also does this process the pre elements which are nested?

Comment: Hi Eswar, the `.*?` part of the regular expression with the tag make it to match any number of attributes (and with no attributes). And I im trying it now with nested `pre's` and it's not working, I will update mi answers with the correct version. Other big problem is with unbalanced `pre`, the regex only match balanced ones.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, by unbalanced Pre , do you mean any Pre element having a starting tag but not ending tag? If so, I don't need to worry in my usecase.

Comment: Yes, the regular expressions don't work good with html, see my updated answer!. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed description, unfortunately only the first option worked for me. I will not be able to use the second option.

Comment: just realized I dint award the bounty. Just did. Cheers :)