# How to replace some tags and remove others with line break in j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsoup

The main problem was to get the content of an html file and remove all tags.
I have read theses questions before:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453047/jsoup-to-strip-only-html-tagsnot-new-line-character)

after reading all of them I decided to use `jsoup` and it really helped me. I also realized how to keep line break and replace `<p>` tags with line break.
now my problem is that I have an html file which has a `<H1>` tag inside which the title of the whole content is available and I wanna keep it with a line break but with jsoup the fist paragraph comes exactly after the title without any line break. can any one help me plz?
the html code I have :

`<DIV class="story-headline">`
`<H1 class="story-title">NFL 2014 predictions</H1>`
`</DIV>`
`<H3 class="story-deck">Our picks for playoff teams, surprises, Super Bowl</H3>`
`<P class="small lighttext">`
`<SPAN class="delimited">Posted: Sep 02, 2014 1:30 PM ET</SPAN>`
`<SPAN>Last Updated: Sep 04, 2014 10:27 AM ET</SPAN>`
`</P>`

and the out put is:

```
NFL 2014 predictionsOur picks for playoff teams, surprises, Super Bowl

Posted: Sep 02, 2014 1:30 PM ETLast Updated: Sep 04, 2014 10:27 AM ET
```

I want it to be:

```
NFL 2014 predictions  
Our picks for playoff teams, surprises, Super Bowl  
Posted: Sep 02, 2014 1:30 PM ET  
Last Updated: Sep 04, 2014 10:27 AM ET
```

Comment: add <br/> after you close ur <div>

Comment: HTML code is my input how should I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hook the `OutputSettings` of the target `Document`, so try the following:

```java
public class HtmlWithLineBreaks 
{

  public String getCleanHtml(Document document)
  {
    document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false)); //makes html() call preserve linebreaks and spacing
    return Jsoup.clean(document.html(),
        "",
        Whitelist.none(),
        new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
  }

  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    File input = new File("/path/to/some/input.html"); //Just replace the input with you own html file source
    Document document;
    try
    {
      document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
      String printOut = new HtmlWithLineBreaks().getCleanHtml(document);
      System.out.println(printOut);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }

}
```

*Optionally* you can insert custom linebreaks after your `<h1>` `<div>` wrapper if you are not satisfied with the provided output:

```java
public String getCleanHtml(Document document)
{
  document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
  document.select("h1").parents().select("div").append("\n"); // Insert a linebreak after the h1 div parent.
  return Jsoup.clean(document.html(),
      "",
      Whitelist.none(),
      new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
}
```

Comment: it doesn't understand `<DIV>` or `<H1>` tags to insert `\n` after end of each. so the output would be like the first one

Comment: Did you give a shot? I assume no because the code introduced already an error which I corrected just now.

Comment: I have also updated the answer on how to insert explicit line breaks, even though `Jsoup` understands your inline blocks and wrap them accordingly.